# Resque-ui causes error message "Tried to use a connection from a child process" to redid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I'm using Resque 1.22.0, Resque-status 0.3.3 and all works well.  If I include the rescue-ui gem, I get the error (from the queue) :

```
failed: #<Redis::InheritedError: Tried to use a connection from a child process without reconnecting. You need to reconnect to Redis after forking.>
```

Removing resque-ui from the rake task code, and leaving it on in the foreground works ok.  Does anyone have any idea how to fix this: very irritating......

Answer (score 0):

That Is was one of the big issue in resque for a while look over here check over [here](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/issues/587)

It something like mysql connection going away problem when a `fork` exit

it close all it connection just the difference over here is instead of `mysql` it `redis`

So the situation is something like this in simpler term

```
#### Resque main worker
redis = Redis.new 
while(true) do 

#### Parent redis connection
redis.blpop(* queue_name)
#### redis queue are polled and message are consumed

#### Resque internally fork to performer the task 

fork {
  #### This fork used the redis connection from the main worker
  #### On exit the fork close the redis connection 
  ##### Perform the background task
}
end

## On Main Worker when the the resque try to use the same connection that was closed it raise the above error
```

how to Solve this

well there are multiple way you can solve this

a) update resque ( it took a while but now the patch is update is resque ) see over [here](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/worker.rb#L149)

b) If updation you not looking at then you could achieve this using resque_hooks something like this

```
Resque.after_fork do 
  Resque.redis.client.reconnect
end
```

c) Upgrade Redis Server:-  This completely sure of this but I noties with  Redis 2.4.6 
not sure of the version though the reconnect was achieve via redis internally(Not sure of whether it was redis or redis client but think for sure reconnect was happening implicitly)

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Try to identify resque process id, kill it and restart the resque server.

Additionally you may try the below

```
Redis.current.client.reconnect
$redis = Redis.current
```